# Show that the Hessian of $f$ is negative definite.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Problem says:

> Show that if $f:A\subset \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$  has a
>   critical point $x_0 \in A$ and we let
>
> $\Delta =$determinant of Hessian of $f$
>
> be evaluated at $x_0$, then $\Delta >0$ and $\partial^2 f/\partial x_1
> >0$ and $  \partial^2 f/\partial x_1 \partial x_1<0$ imply $f$ has a local maximum at $x_0$

I proved the case when $f$ has a local minimum at $x_0$.

It suffices to show that $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{2}}\\
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\partial x_{2}}
\end{array}\right)$
  is positive definite, that is, for any $v=(x,y)^{T}\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\backslash\{(0,0)\}
$ ,

$(\begin{array}{cc}
x & y\end{array})\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right)>0$

So, $a(x+\frac{b}{a}y)^{2}+(c-\frac{b^{2}}{a})y^{2}>0$

By assumption $a>0$
  and $ac-b^{2}>0$
 , we get desired one.

But the problem is to show that $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{2}}\\
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\partial x_{2}}
\end{array}\right)$
  is negative definite so that f
  has a local minimum at $x_{0}$
 .

$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{2}}\\
\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\partial x_{2}}
\end{array}\right)$
  is negative definite is equivalent to $a(x+\frac{b}{a}y)^{2}+(c-\frac{b^{2}}{a})y^{2}<0$
  for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash\{(0,0)\}$
 . But given condition says only $a>0$
  and $ac-b^{2}<0$
 , i.e., $a(x+\frac{b}{a}y)^{2}>0$
  and $(c-\frac{b^{2}}{a})y^{2}>0$
 . How could I show that the sum of them is negative?

Comment: But it just shows that the Hessian is not positive definite, isn't it?

Comment: How are you possible computing partials and $f$ is a function of one variable??

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I fixed them.

Comment: This is part of the second derivative test for multivariable functions which is very non-trivial. You can get some motivation from any calculus textbook.